# Generalization of Buffons 'noodle'

Tags: probability, expected-value

I had read an interesting paper a few years back on Buffons 'noodle' (https://doi.org/10.2307/2317945) and when attempting a problem recently I thought I could use it as a tool.

I have provided a short summary of the background information in the first header which can be skipped if you are already aware of the problem.

## Buffon's needle & noodle

### Needle

The theorem developed in the paper is a substantial generalization of the famous Buffons needle problem that says given a grid of parallel lines separated by a common distance $d$ the probability that a uniformly 'randomly' thrown 'needle' of length $l\leq a$ will intersect of the lines is $$P=\frac{2l}{\pi d}$$.
'Randomly' is only in quotations since the original problem refers to a infinite grid and a uniform random distribution over R^2 doesn't make much sense, so for the problem's sake often only a small finite grid is considered WLOG.

### The noodle

Ramaley derives a theorem that generalized the above fact by proving that the expected number of a 'squiggly noodle' of length $l$ (this time not constrained) on the same parallel grid with distances $d$ is $$E=\frac{2l}{\pi d}$$.

'Squiggly noodle' here can be mathematically understood as any rectifiable curve which can be approximated uniformly by a sequence of line segments.

## My question

*How can we extend this notion of Ramaley's noodles to a rectangular grid of length $a$ and $b$ or maybe even further for any tiling pattern?*

I would greatly appreciate some hints on how I can approach solving this as I wanted to work on it as a mini project for some research experience.

#### Motivation (not strictly relevant to the problem)

I was inspired to try and prove this myself for the rectangular case as it was very similar to a problem I was trying to solve which involved a convex shape being thrown 'randomly' on a grid. (Note this is basically identical to the theorem of Gnedenko which Ramaley references in the paper but with a grid instead of the parallel lines they used).

My conjecture was that due to the startling similarity of Ramaleys generalization, the rectangular grid problem would also have a similar structure to the rectangular grid version of Buffon's needle (which has been solved sometimes referred to as the Laplace extension of Buffon's needle).

The Laplace problem says that for a rectangular grid of length $a$, breadth $b$ and 'needle' of length $l \leq \min\{a,b\}$ the probability the needle intersects with the grid is

$$P(A \text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)=\frac{2l(a+b)-l^2}{\pi ab}$$
Where events $A$ and $B$ can be interpreted as the event in which the needle intersects the parallel lines separated at distance $a,b$ respectively.

I had thought maybe the Expected value for line crossings would simply be in the same structure for the 'noodle'.I thought to check with Monte Carlo simulations before attempting to 'prove' it and the formula doesn't appear to hold and seems to undercount.

Comment: Ah, this (the noodle) is a well known identity and used in stereology to estimate the length of the noodles :-) I don't have time right now, but as long as the noodle has random orientation (uniform random rotation), it does not matter for the expected number of intersections if you use a rectangular grid, it only matters for the variance of the number of intersections. You can just sum the two expectations from the horizontal and the vertical grid. I'll come back at some later point.

Comment: Do you want the mean number of intersection points (can be many, and is easy), or are you after counting "intersect or not" (more tedious)?

Comment: I think mean number of intersection points would just be E(A)+E(B) right? In the question I was really just looking to verify a formula for that exactly. But since then I've just been toying around with this setup too. It would be interesting to determine probability of "intersect or not" too. Do you have any ideas for counting that?

Comment: Yes, E(A) +E(B) is the mean intersection count. For the other question, it helps to know what a Minkowsky sum is (maybe I'll expand in an answer) . Btw, does this question relate to your recent question about Poisson distribution? It sounds like you are working on a stochastic geometry project :-)

Comment: Well I've heard of a minkowsky sum, but just the basic definition and saw it in a few analysis problems nothing very deep. Thanks for you help with that other problem it was so tough to find a reference. They aren't related however just happens to be I'm stumbling across some probability after a long time. For this question in particular the problem I was trying to solve is basically exactly the same one Gndecko did in that reference but just for the 2d grid case. I left it a bit vague cuz i wanted to try to fill in the details. But now it seems like it's quite complicated.

Comment: Oh i just read your second comment with the hint i will try and approach it with that when i have some free time between school applications. Thanks again you've been really helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147596/discussion-between-ute-and-bhoris-dhanjal).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a simulation with the dimensions of the grid being $a=b=1$ and the lines being of size $l=0.6$.

I made the simulation by generating lines based on uniformly distributed starting points and uniformly distributed directions.

A potential analytical computation may use the same approach and integrate $$\int_0^a\int_0^b f(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$ where $f(x,y)$ is the probability that a certain starting point generates a line withing the $a$ by $b$ rectangle. For the grid of parallel lines this can be computed, but for the rectangular grid this seems more difficult.

[image: example of simulation]

---

I chose the parameters in the above simulation to show the interesting pattern where the highest density is neither at the center, nor the edge. Depending on the length of the needles, this can change a lot. Long needles with size $\approx 1$ will only not cross the gridlines when they start near the edge (from the middle they will cross the boundary gridlines whatever the direction), short needles with size $l \ll 1$ will always be inside the box when they are at the center, but not when they are at the edges. The size $l=0.6$ is a situation in between both cases.

I guess that an analytical approach will need to consider multiple ranges and add them up. It is not gonna be a simple formula.

Comment: What you simulated is the Laplace extension to Buffons needle. That already has an exact solution I've mentioned it in the question. Here's a reference https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/on-laplaces-extension-of-the-buffon-needle-problem

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. That solution seems simple and takes the sum of probabilities of crossing either vertical/horizontal line minus the probability of crossing both (although adjustments need to be made for l>a and l>b). Now I am not sure what the question is, how does this Laplace extension not answer your problem?

Comment: Cause that's for the straight needle case. I was trying to solve it for the wiggly noodle (i.e. uniformly approximatef rectifiable curve) case. I think i can use that to solve the problem for any arbitrary convex shape thrown onto a grid.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal the expectation for the expected number of times that a wiggly noodle crosses a line is just the same as the sum of the expectations that it's individual needles cross a line. (There might be details like considerations about what to do when a needle crosses multiple lines, but basically it is just multiplying the expectation for a single needle).

Comment: Yea that's what I thought too but my code didn't match up. Maybe I should try it again could have been a mistake in the program. I don't really see any reason why the proof for grid modified in the same way as Ramaley's shouldn't work.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal maybe it is in the details that I shortly mentioned. Could you express more precisely what expectation value you are estimating with your code. You mention 'the expected number', but what is that exactly? If you regard the expected value of line crossings then, depending on the interpretation you should use: $$P(A)+P(B)$$ instead of $$P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$ The latter counts multiple line crossings by the same needle segment of the noodle, as a single line crossing.